# Bind Flex component text to xml Node text for a desktop application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a tabNavigator  with three tabs, on 2 tab pages I have a richtext control id = "characters" and id = "worlds", and on one a textarea control id = "objects".

How do I bind these to an xml file with nodes

(root>

(characters>*** //text from richtext.text id = "characters" must go here on save***(characters>

(worlds> ***//text from richtext.text id = "worlds" must go here on save***(/worlds>

(objects>*** //text from textarea.text id = "objets" must go here on save***(/objects>

(/root>

(had to use brackets otherwise they dont show)

AND THEN

When I open the saved file the text in the xml nodes must write back into the three components in the tabnavigator.

Please help, I am  doing a course and my assignment is to write a desktop software and save all user input in xml and I am just not getting it.

Thanks for any help and patience

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep the XML/Actionscript Object Serialization seperate from anything to do with saving the state of your application/document.

To keep things simple you could create a presentation Model for your three views to bind all the data from your views like so:

PresentationModel.as

```
[Bindable]
public var characters:String;

[Bindable]
public var worlds:String;

[Bindable]
public var objects:String;
```

Once you have all your data collected from your users input you could then either use Flex based serialization libraries to change value/complex object to XML or simply use the objects inside of a method to manually construct your XML file.